# copy all files to central repository through git

Tags: git

we are using git for our project and we are doing project built on magento.we need to use lot of plugins for that.

so when we copied a plugin [50 file] to server , and than we want to move these files to the central repository, when we tried **git add .**  its not working. is there any way to add all 50 files to central repository.

because its very difficult to edit all 50 files and than adding files to central repository.please help me to find solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: `git add` supports wildcards (`*`).  For example, if you had 50 files under the path `path/to/file/` you could type `git add path/to/file/*` and it would add all the files there.

Comment: will it add copied files also. copied files from local desktop and i didt edited those files in server

Comment: This question is a bit vague, but yes, `git add` should add untracked files in the same location.  If you don't want these files to be versioned, you should add them to your `.gitignore` file before making a commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `git add -A` which adds all files to your git, following the rules of your `.gitignore`.

You can also use `git add -A --dry-run` to test if you have set up your `.gitignore` properly.

Comment: will it add copied files also. copied files from local desktop and i didt edited those files in server

Comment: Did the files change? If not, git shouldnt add them again. Or dont you want them to be tracked at all? Then you should probably add them to `.gitignore`.